# Nginx, Weblogic, and reverse proxy by path

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, weblogic

I'm having issues getting my reverse proxy to work when using a path in nginx. What I am trying to do is have one address for an application, and dictate the environment with the path. Depending on the path, it would point to a different server. I'm able to get the reverse proxy working when using a direct link, but using a path is getting a 404 error.

app.foo.bar/dev = 404 error
devapp.foo.bar = success

What have I done wrong on app.foo.bar/dev ?

Here is the reverse proxy setup that is working, but I'd rather not use:

```
server  {
  listen  80;   # DEV Application Proxy
  server_name  devapp.foo.bar;
  location  / {
    proxy_pass  http://appserver.foo.bar:7010;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
        port_in_redirect off;
        proxy_redirect   http://appserver.foo.bar:7010/ /;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    }
  }
```

Here is a portion of what I am wanting to do by using path, but getting 404 error.

```
# APP Environment Proxy

server {

  listen 80;
  server_name app.foo.bar;
     location /dev {
      proxy_pass http://appserver.foo.bar:7010;
      proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
      port_in_redirect off;
      proxy_redirect     http://appserver.foo.bar:7010 /;
      proxy_connect_timeout 300;

  }
}
```

I've googled this type of setup, but I'm not able find a solution. Thanks in advance for the any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `proxy_pass http://appserver.foo.bar:7010;`, nginx appends the normalized URI to the request URL passed to backend.

So, when you request `http://app.foo.bar/dev`, the request goes to `http://appserver.foo.bar:7010/dev`. If your dev server doesn't have this path, then it will return 404, which nginx returns to the client.

If you want all requests starting with `http://app.foo.bar/dev` to go to `http://appserver.foo.bar:7010` such that all rest of the URI is added to the backend server URI, then you can use this configuration:

```
location ~ ^/dev(.+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://appserver.foo.bar:7010$1$is_args$args;
    ...
}
```

So, we capture the part after `/dev` with regex to a variable, and then we add that variable to end of `proxy_pass` path.

Comment: In this case I want it to go to the root of http://appserver.foo.bar:7010 the issue with the solution you've shown is that is seems to point to the prd instance. What I'm wanting is / = prodserver:port/ /dev=devserver:port/ /uat=uatserver:port/ and /sit=sitsitserver:port/

Comment: If you want `/dev` go to a different server, just change the `proxy_pass` destination accordingly.